# What is the best ng-change/ngChange event for Angular 5 to fire a custom function?

Tags: angular, input, angular5, angularjs-ng-change

I am trying to get the ng-change event to update a function I wrote by doing this. For now, the function only logs "I am here" to the console. I am implementing it like this:

```
<input type="number" ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="3" min="5" max="100" class="form-control" name="percentOwnership" (ng-change)="fullyOwned()"  [(ngModel)]="individualowner.percentOwnership">
```

I have tried to take off the one-way binding parens and also adding the two-way binding parens and brackets, but nothing fires my function to log "I am here" to the console.

I have also tried these combinations by using "change" and "ngModelChange". Still, nothing fires my function. I am using Angular 5.2.9

Comment: Sir or madam, you spelled it wrong. Read the documentation. It is `(ngChange)` or `(ngModelChange)`

Comment: ngChange also does not work for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `[ngModel]` and `(ngModelChange)` separately.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <input type="number" [ngModel]="percent" (ngModelChange)="onPercentChange($event)" />
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  percent = 20;

  onPercentChange(percent: number) {
    console.log('here');  

    this.percent = percent;
  }
}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zyaqb8)

Also your `min="5"` `max="100"` validations will not work as expected. They have been removed in `Angular 4.2`. [Read more about the issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17491#issuecomment-308900276).